# Which sent event for UIButton should I use for swiping on Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

[image]

I am trying to create a Xylophone app and trying to achive play notes without lifting my finger between UIButton components. Which Event should I use to achive that?

I tried both **Touch up Inside** and **Touch Drag Enter** events but both of them didn't work as intended.

Comment: You should get the location of the touch instead of introducing too many buttons. Also, all button events are triggered only when you initial the touch event, starting from them, and do not work when you come from another button.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can achieve playing notes immediately when touching the button using the event "Touch Down"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this using control events on the xylophone blocks, because a control event cannot magically transfer from one view to another (your intent being to slide between xylophone blocks without lifting a finger as a way of changing notes). Don't use any control events. Don't use any controls. Don't use buttons.  Use views to represent the xylophone blocks. Implement raw touch detection events on the background behind those views.

Comment: I think I know the course he enrolled in and the task was to do it with buttons, however, that would work just as fine

Comment: @not_a_nerd We don't do homework for people; we answer questions. A direct question was asked and I've given an answer to it _as posed_ — a correct answer, by the way; your comment ("If I understand you correctly") does _not_ solve the problem _as posed_.

Comment: I thought it was meant like that.